# JSF to JQuery Component Integration

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, richfaces

Since any JSF page gets transformed at the server side into its equivalent HTML and sent to the client for rendering, and JQuery at the client side takes the HTML and re renders it.

In theory it should be possible to take the HTML that is a generated by JSF and wrap it into JQuery, if so I would like to know how it's done. Specifically using RichFaces as the JSF implementation if possible.

```
<rich:dataTable id="table">          
  <rich:column>

  </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

The above snippet of JSF is transformed into it's equivalent HTML which is this

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Shouldn't it be possible to do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#table').dataTable();
}
</script>
```

I've already tried that but it doesn't seem to work.

So please if anyone has any hints, I'd be more than grateful.

Comment: are you sure that the  $(document).ready(function () {
 is being called ? place alert('a') to see... cause it should work

Comment: yes it's now called thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixing JSF and jquery is doable but there are some gotchas.

JSF is taking over your ids, so if table is in a form with id "form", the actual element id in html would be by default "form:table". I think jquery could have a problem with colon in a selector, so you may mark your table with a class and select by that:

```
<rich:dataTable styleClass="my-table">          
  <rich:column>

  </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

and set selector as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.my-table').dataTable();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have included example in my answer.

Comment: I did try your code and it added the functionality of the jquery data table to my rich faces table,except that the table doesn't react to the actions taken by the jquey data table controllers, for instance when if I have a table with 20 rows, and only 10 are shown at a time, when I navigate to the next page the message is changed to displaying from 11 - 20, but the data is not shown on the table, like the action to navigate was never taken, any hints?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with RichFaces, so you may want to ask another question. What you could try though is substitute rich:dataTable with h:dataTable and rich:column with h:column. The latter should be free of any potentially conflicting scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The Id's of the JSF components are generated by combining the Id's of the containers on the hierarchy with a : separator. Not all the containers count, I don't remember exactly the rules.

Normally some JSF libraries have some client side API to get the component ID's I don't know for richfaces.

Anyway, if you'd like to use jQuery based JSF, take a look at primefaces.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be a '$' name spacing conflict arisen by the Jquery and rich faces component which is made of Prototype.js.Try using jQuery.noconflict() method. I had a similar problem of making the jquery work with richfaces jquery.noconflict() did the trick..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
 });
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Good Luck!