# Attach Jquery events to JSF data tables

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces

Since we can apply JQuery to any JSF rendered components, as in the following question

[JSF to JQuery Component Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515384/jsf-to-jquery-component-integration)

After having tried that, it did work I can successfully integrate JQuery into JSF, but the problem is that whenever I re-render the h:dataTable for instance, JQuery stops working, 
-I'm using RichFaces and the a4j, by the way-.

For example, I have a data table as follows

```
<h:dataTable id="someDataTable" value="#{backingBean.someDataModel}" var="item" styleClass="table">
   <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{item.text}"/>
   </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

and I have a button that when clicked re-renders the dataTable, and repopulate it with new data.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Click" reRender="someDataTable"/>
```

and not to forget I have this script in the page

```
<script>
  jQuery.noConflict();
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery('.table').dataTable({
    "bSort": false}); 
    });
</script>
```

Now when the page is first loaded, sorting works fine, but whenever I click the button to re-render the table, the table is successfully populated with the new data from the backing bean, but the sorting doesn't work anymore.

From what I guess, I think this might has something to do with the

```
jQuery(document).ready()
```

which applies the

```
jQuery.('.table').dataTable();
```

only when the document is ready, so I was wondering if there's some events in jQuery that I can attach to the dataTable re-render event, as I'm no guru at JQuery or JS.

Comment: Can you show use the button / link that re-renders the table? Is it done with Ajax?

Comment: yes I can use it and it works perfectly, please notice that the above data table code is only a snippet, I have no problem updating the values of the data table, nor with the ajax events

Comment: I don't know how richfaces works, but I'd try `<a4j:commandButton value="Click" reRender="someDataTable" oncomplete="reRenderJQuery()/>` where `reRenderJQuery()` is a javascript function that simply does `jQuery('.table').dataTable({
    "bSort": false}); 
    });
`, but I don't know if Richfaces' commandButton handles ajax events!

Comment: I'll try that and let you know

Comment: I did try that and still it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-execute the script when the ajax request has completed.

First refactor your script into a reuseable function.

```html
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        initDataTable();
    });
    function initDataTable() {
        jQuery('.table').dataTable({
            "bSort": false
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Then invoke the same function in `oncomplete` of `<a4j:commandButton>`.

```html
<a4j:commandButton ... oncomplete="initDataTable()" />
```